# other ways of getting instances besides getChildByName()

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have many MovieClips and each has a name like "mcDummyClosed" and then and instance name "slideDummyClosed". Another MovieClip has a link to e.g. slideDummyClosed which I then call DummyClosed. I add a MouseEvent.CLICK event to DummyClosed.

Now without adding slideDummyClosed to the stage nor any other MovieClip can I with a string containing it's name get that instance?

I've tried using getChildByName() but that only seems to work if I've already added the MC to be found and added before.
My code looks something like this:

```
public function lookHere(e:MouseEvent){
    //this is the function called by e.g. DummyClosed
    currentView.removeChildAt(0); //remove the MC that was here before
    var slideName:String = 'slide' + e.target.name; //the name of the instance

    currentView.addChild(??); //how do I add slideName (e.g. slideDummyClosed) here?
}
```

Comment: If you use FlashDevelop and export the Symbol a stub class will automatically be generated for you with all the appropriate member names.  Basically cutting out the getChildByName step.  I tend to end up with things like, a symbol named com.company.project.AFunnyAnimation and then i create a class in my project called com.company.project.FunnyAnimation that inherits AFunnyAnimation (exposed via the export of a SWC).  That way, inside FunnyAnimation Class I can access all the named members of AFunnyAnimation in normal member notation.  This is really a question of workflow though.

Comment: I read that as "McDummyClosed" at first, like "McDonalds", rather than "moveclipDummyClosed" and it made me lol.  It could be fun to classify variables by giving them ranks like "sirDouble" or "mrFloat".  Anyway, it seems you need to keep track of your object instances by name as they're created, which you could do by adding them by name to a flash.utils.Dictionary object, and retrieving the instances by name from it later.

Answer (score 1):

[getDefinitionByName()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/langref/flash/utils/package.html) might work here. It looks about like what you want, but I've never used it personally.

Comment: yes from the sounds of it this is what you want. You will need to set the linkage for each clip in the library (click on properties for each MovieClip in the library and check export for ActionScript). The classname specified will be the required string. Then to use getDefinitionByName should look something like var myClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("className") as Class; var img:MovieClip = new myClass();

Comment: Doesn't getDefinitionByName just return the class but not the specific instance of that class? I've aldready created the instances of the classes before I go into lookHere.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to find a specific movieclip with just using the name of it taken from the "e.target.name" ?

I take it that you dont click the same target as you want to modify. 
One solution is to save all mc's in an array and then loop through it comparing their names and then returning the matching one.

Comment: That would work, I was just hoping AS3 had a method or class that would allow me to find and call an instance of an object using it's name.

Comment: the getChildbyName("") is such a function but as you noticed it only works for displayObjects which have been added to the displayList in some way. 

Its usually a good idea to save references of all created object in arrays/vectors så the easily can be disposed of when not used anymore.